# How can I populate an instance of an object with random values?

Tags: c#, autofixture

Is there any way I can give AutoFixture an instance of an object and have it go through all the setters and set random data? The wiki examples only show how to obtain an instance from AutoFixture, e.g.

```
var autoGeneratedClass = fixture.Create<ComplexParent>();
```

My example use case is a factory method which generate instances of objects with dynamic properties based on a configuration. I want to test that my methods correctly, detect and interact (e.g. copy) these dynamic properties.

```
dynamic dynamicPropertyObject1 = factoryMethod(configuration);
dynamic dynamicPropertyObject2 = factoryMethod(configuration);
dynamicPropertyObject1.propA = random.Next();
dynamicPropertyObject1.CopyTo(dynamicPropertyObject2); 
Assert.That(dynamicPropertyObject2.propA, Is.EqualTo(dynamicPropertyObject1.propA);
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything? What was it? What did it do wrong? Can you generate the random data? Can you introspect on the instance? More detail required...

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: We have an extremely complex factory method that goes off and creates an object with a nested, interacting types underneath. To further complicate things, some of the types are created dynamically in the factory method as they can have dynamic properties specified dynamically by passing in a configuration. In order to fully test these types, I need to use the dynamically created objects generated from the factory method.

Comment: @AndrewCorcoran Update on what? Since you have factory methods, why don't you just call them?

Comment: Our factory method creates a new type using IL and returns an instance of it. We want to populate this instance with random data rarther than c# defaults.

Answer (score 2):

AutoFixture has a lot of built-in heuristics for creating objects, including some for factory methods.

If AutoFixture finds no public constructors on a type, it starts to look for factory methods; i.e. static methods that return objects of the type of the class that defines that static method, e.g.

```
public class Foo
{
    public static Foo CreateFoo();

    // ... other members
}
```

If, on the other hand, a factory method exists on *another* class, you'll need to help AutoFixture a bit. The easiest way would be to use the `Customize` method:

```
fixture.Customize<Foo>(c => c
    .FromFactory(() => FooFactory.CreateFoo())
    .WithAutoProperties());
```

When you subsequently ask a `Fixture` object for a `Foo` object, `FooFactory.CreateFoo()` will be invoked, and because of `WithAutoProperties` that object will be populated with data created by AutoFixture.